# how to get around run-time error 1004 when converting text to numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new to vba and am having some issue running this code to convert text to numbers:

```
Dim rLastR As Range, rLastC As Range, rUsedRange As Range
Set rLastR = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rLastC = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rUsedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B15", Cells(rLastR.Row, rLastC.Column))
For Each rUsedRange In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection).Areas
    rUsedRange.Value = rUsedRange.Value -------> run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error*
Next rUsedRange
```

I was wondering if this error occurs because the file I tried to run it on has too many cell formats. It ran fine on other files. Is there a way to refine this code so that I could circumvent this problem?

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to convert cells containing ranges/$/% (stored as text) to number. I tried

a) changing the numberformat to general, but because of the too many cell formats error, excel wasn't able to change the numberformat;

b) using the following code, but it converts my stored-as-text numbers all to 0 as well

```
For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = Val(r.Value)
Next
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly because `rUsedRange` is set as a range right before that.  Try say `For Each tempUsedRange in ... // tempUsedRange.Value = tempUsedRange.Value` instead?

Comment: Why not just use `Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection).Cells`? Or have another array to store the Value then put it back into the Range?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the long code, it will not do what you want. The latter code is fine and it should work with some better development like below. Changing the value will not work if you don't change the format of the cell too. When you have a Text format, if you tell Excel to convert blank to number it will convert it to 0, that is why you have zeros all over.

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumbers()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet 'change as needed

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0        

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rng
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                cell.NumberFormat = "General"
                cell.Value = Val(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all! lbo, I tried your suggested code. It took a while for excel to run it on my system, but otherwise it worked great! Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good! Please hit the checkmark on the upper left corner of this post to accept this as the right answer. You can upvote it with the triangles too. This way the answerer gets credits and also you will get credit for that, plus your question will be considered answered and will not be in the unanswered questions queue